# CSS Using wildcard * all elements within a :not()

Tags: css, selector

I've written bits of JS that select elements within a bootstrap modal. To ensure that said JS only selects elements that belong to the modal itself (i.e within its header/footer), but excludes any element from the modal's body, I'm appending the following piece of select to my selectors :

```
:not(.modal-body *)
```

For example, if I select `.btn:not(.modal-body *)` in my modal, this will exclude any `.btn` present within the modal's body and only return the ones from the header/footer of the modal.

However, this selector seems to be not supported in some broswers that give the following error :

```
Message: 'Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': '.modal-footer:not(.modal-body *)' is not a valid selector.'
```

So I was wondering if there is an alternative way to create such a selector without using the asterisk within the not pseudo-class, which I'm assuming is the cause of the error.

Comment: You should give the header and footer a class and select them positively.

Comment: `:not` is not a subquery selector, right? It's content only applies the element that has been selected. Are you looking for `:is` or `:has`?

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
@somethinghere I just wanted to exclude the children of .modal-body element from the search. I suppose I could have used `:is` (didn't know about it) somehow instead. as for `:has`, I've read it's not very well supported either.

Comment: `:has` is currently pretty decently supported, its just rather recent, so two year old browsers that haven't been updated don't yet support it - but all browsers updated recently do, so if it's not to harmful you can use it already. `:not` just doesn't allow for subqueries - only queries on the element itself, so basically "Does the selected element NOT have this or that?" and _not_ "Does the selected element NOT have children that have this or that?".

Comment: It probably isn't the asterisk that's  the problem, but the complex selector. Earlier versions of `:not()` only allowed a simple selector argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using the child combinator (>) to select direct children of the modal header/footer.

For CSS

```
.modal:not(.modal-body) .btn {
    /* your styles */
}
```

For JavaScript

```
document.querySelectorAll('.modal > :not(.modal-body) .btn');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However the button case was just an example. The direct child operator might have helped in this case, but I was looking for something more generally applicable.

Comment: `.modal:not(.modal-body) .btn` or `.modal > :not(.modal-body) .btn`. wouldn't it be generalized now.